# Espacio datafiles en ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-19c

Tengo una duda por un tema de espacio en una BD de oracle 19 en windows, exporte un esquema con la función EXPDP, el archivo .dmp que se generó pesa aproximadamente 20 GB, pero al momento de realizar el IMPDP llena por completo el datafile de 33GB y me toco agregar otro datafile para que lograra continuar la importación.

No tengo mucha experiencia en oracle, acaso un archivo .dmp se puede decir que viene comprimido?

Cabe aclarar que tengo una tabla que tiene 270 millones de registros y para cargar esa información rápidamente hice un sqlloader, pero para que fuera más rápido elimine los indices y restricciones, una vez cargue los datos, volví a crear los indices y estos ocuparon bastante espacio en el datafile.

Compile el esquema y actualice estadisticas, no sé, si estoy haciendo algo mal o es normal que un esquema que pesaba originalmente 20GB ocupe más de un datafile?

O si me falta realizar algún tipo de confirmación como un commit para que suelte espacio de memoria en algún lado, no sé.

De antemano agradezco cualquier comentario que me ayude a entender.

Comment: Es normal, un volcado de datos sólo incluye la definición de los índices, mas no el contenido, ya que éste se puede generar a partir de los registros de las tablas. No es raro que los índices ocupen mas espacio que sólo la tabla. Nota que la estructura de almacenamiento en Oracle es un poco mas compleja (segmento, extensión y bloque) y que no necesariamente resulta exactamente la misma al importar; considera que de tu segundo datafile tal vez sólo se ocupan unos cuantos bytes.